# equation of a rotated circle

Tags: geometry

In 3d space i have a circle in the $xz$ plane defined by equation  $(x-i)^2+(z-k)^2=r^2$.  If this circle is rotated through $\theta$ degrees around the line $z=k$ or by $\phi$ degrees around the line $x=i$ or both.  What now is the equation?

Comment: Those are not lines in three dimensions. Both $z=k$ and $x=i$ describe planes.

Answer (score 0):

For a rotation around $z=k$, the resulting circle is the intersection between the sphere $(x-i)^2+(z-k)^2+y^2=r^2$ and the plane $y=\tan\theta(z-k)$.

Comment: does it also hold for $x=i$ is the intersection of sphere and plane $y=tan\phi(i-x)$

Comment: Yes it does. Be careful to adjust the sign depending on how you choose the rotation angle.

Comment: is there any simple way to combine both $\theta$ and $\phi$ into one equation for a plane

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What is the result you need?

Comment: something like $y=tan \theta(z-k)+tan \phi(x-i)$

Comment: That is a plane passing through the center of the sphere and its intersection with the sphere is a rotated circle.

Answer (score 0):

The given circle is better described in parametric form

$ r(t) = V_0 +  \cos t \ V_1 + \sin t \ V_2 $

where $V_0 = [ i, 0, k ]^T , V_1 = [r, 0, 0]^T , V_2 = [0, 0, r]^T $

To rotate the circle about the axis ($y = 0, z = k$) gives the equation of the axis as  $a(t) = V_0 + t [1, 0, 0 ]^T $ which the line parallel to the $x$-axis and passing through $V_0$.  The image of $r(t)$ under this rotation is

$r'(t) = V_0 + R_1 (r(t) - V_0)  = V_0 + \cos t \ R_1 V_1 + \sin \ R_1 V_2 = V_0 + \cos t \ W_1 + \sin t \ W_2 $

$R_1$ is the rotation matrix about the $x$ axis, and is given by

$ R_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \cos \theta && - \sin \theta \\ 0 && \sin \theta && \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} $

Hence,

$ W_1 =R_1 V_1 = V_1 = [r, 0, 0]^T , W_2 =R_1 V_2 = [0, - r \sin \theta , r \cos \theta ] $

To rotate this rotated circle about the line ($y = 0, x = i$), the axis of rotation is given $a(t) = V_0 + t [0, 0, 1]^T $ , the same as above applies, but now the rotation matrix is given by

$ R_3 = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \phi && -\sin \phi && 0 \\ \sin \phi && \cos \phi && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

The image of $r'(t)$ is

$r''(t) = V_0 + \cos t \ R_3 W_1 + \sin t \ R_3 W_2 = V_0 + \cos t \ X_1 + \sin t \ X_2 $

Hence,

$X_1 = [ r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi, 0 ]^T , X_2 = [r \sin \theta \sin \phi , - r  \sin \theta \cos \phi , r \cos \theta ]^T$